# multi bundle accordion effect with anchor button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i am working on one website where i need navbar or instead i can use anchor button for displaying my content,here i have problem with displaying content on load.first time as i click on **any button** all expanded item get collapsed and than on second click it will follow instruction as i given in code java script.

here is what i did:

```js
$('#button-1').click(function(e) {
  $('#collapseOne').collapse('show');
  $('#collapseTwo').collapse('show')
  $('#collapseThree').collapse('show');
  $('#collapsefour').collapse('show')
});
$('#button-2').click(function(e) {
  $('#collapseOne').collapse('hide');
  $('#collapseTwo').collapse('show')
  $('#collapseThree').collapse('show');
  $('#collapsefour').collapse('show')
});
$('#button-3').click(function(e) {
  $('#collapseOne').collapse('hide');
  $('#collapseTwo').collapse('hide')
  $('#collapseThree').collapse('show');
  $('#collapsefour').collapse('show')
});
$('#button-4').click(function(e) {
  $('#collapseOne').collapse('hide');
  $('#collapseTwo').collapse('hide')
  $('#collapseThree').collapse('hide');
  $('#collapsefour').collapse('show')
});
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#accordion" id="button-1" class="btn btn-primary">button 1</a>
<a href="#accordion" id="button-2" class="btn btn-primary">button 2</a>
<a href="#accordion" id="button-3" class="btn btn-primary">button 3</a>
<a href="#accordion" id="button-4" class="btn btn-primary">button 4</a>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
</div>
<div>
  <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne"></a></h4></div>
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
  <div class="panel-body">
  test test test
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapsetwo"></a></h4></div>
<div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
  <div class="panel-body">
   test-1 test-1 test-1
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree"></a></h4></div>
<div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
  <div class="panel-body">
   test-2 test-2 test-2 test-2
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapsefour"></a></h4></div>
<div id="collapsefour" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
  <div class="panel-body">
    test-3 test-3 test-3
  </div>
</div>
```

example :[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/x6skn6mz/2/)

Comment: Do you want to display the contents in page load? or you just want to display the contents on button click?

Comment: So do you want something like this: the content should not display on load and then after you click on some button, you want to show the content in that particular manner?

Comment: i want to display all content on page load,it will give user both experience that if they scroll down they can see all content or even by clicking on button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do following way easily using `show()` and `hide()`

```js
$('#button-1').click(function(e) {
  $('#collapseOne').show("normal");
  $('#collapseTwo').show("normal");
  $('#collapseThree').show("normal");
  $('#collapsefour').show("normal");
});
$('#button-2').click(function(e) {
  $('#collapseOne').hide("normal");
  $('#collapseTwo').show("normal");
  $('#collapseThree').show("normal");
  $('#collapsefour').show("normal");
});
$('#button-3').click(function(e) {
  $('#collapseOne').hide("normal");
  $('#collapseTwo').hide("normal");
  $('#collapseThree').show("normal");
  $('#collapsefour').show("normal");
});
$('#button-4').click(function(e) {
  $('#collapseOne').hide("normal");
  $('#collapseTwo').hide("normal");
  $('#collapseThree').hide("normal");
  $('#collapsefour').show("normal");
});
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#accordion" id="button-1" class="btn btn-primary">button 1</a>
<a href="#accordion" id="button-2" class="btn btn-primary">button 2</a>
<a href="#accordion" id="button-3" class="btn btn-primary">button 3</a>
<a href="#accordion" id="button-4" class="btn btn-primary">button 4</a>
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
</div>
<div>
  <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne"></a></h4></div>
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
  <div class="panel-body">
  test test test
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapsetwo"></a></h4></div>
<div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
  <div class="panel-body">
   test-1 test-1 test-1
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree"></a></h4></div>
<div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
  <div class="panel-body">
   test-2 test-2 test-2 test-2
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <h4 class="panel-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapsefour"></a></h4></div>
<div id="collapsefour" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
  <div class="panel-body">
    test-3 test-3 test-3
  </div>
</div>
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x6skn6mz/3/)**

Comment: thank's for your help.even i tried fast,slow in java script it also help me to design good.